# Handling Endpoint exceptions in WCF

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, exception, endpoint

in my application (Windows Phone), I generate a connection to a WCF web service dynamically via code behind.
The user must specify the url of the Web Service then I create my EndPointAddress and Binding, and it works well.
But if the user enter a invalid url, an exception is thrown :

"System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException -> There Was no endpoint listening at [address of the service] That Could accept the message. This Is Often Caused By An incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

The innerexception is quite classic : "The remote server Returned an error: NotFound at InnerException."

The problem: I can not handle this exception. I tried many things found here without success.

Is there any solution?

The only thing I could find is surronding some methods in the Reference.cs, which is definitly not a good idea ...!

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english :) !

My actual code looks like this, but it doesn't catch the exception =>

```
        MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(myBinding, myEndpointAddress);
        try
        {
            client.RegisterUserCompleted += new EventHandler<RegisterUserCompletedEventArgs>(client_RegisterUserCompleted);
            client.RegisterUserAsync();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            client.Abort();
        }

        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            client.Abort();
        }

        catch (CommunicationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            client.Abort();
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
            client.Abort();
        }
        finally
        {
            client.CloseAsync();
        }
```

Comment: How, exactly, do you want to "handle" this exception? Also, exactly at what point is the exception raised?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is solved.
The solution is : the uri have to be test before creating the client.
To do it, I make a WebRequest and catch the exception in the WebResponse :

```
public void ValidateUri(String uri)
    {
        if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) return;
        request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ValidateUriCallback), null);
    }

    private WebRequest request;
    private void ValidateUriCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            WebResponse httpResponse = (WebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

            // Create the client here
            ServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(myBinding, myEndpointAddress);
        client.RegisterUserCompleted += new EventHandler<RegisterUserCompletedEventArgs>(client_RegisterUserCompleted);
        client.RegisterUserAsync();

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            var response = ex.Response as System.Net.HttpWebResponse;
    if (response!=null 
        && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The web service address is not valid", "Sorry", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                 });
    }
        }
```

Comment: I had this issue years later on a Xamarin app. I created ValidateUri as a function on App.cs, and passed in the callback to that - this way I could use the same function anywhere in my app and handle the error case differently, depending on the service I needed: `public static void TestWebAccess(string uri, ref WebRequest request, Action<IAsyncResult> callBack)`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need move your try catches to the client_RegisterUserCompleted method and wrap around the `var x = e.Result;`</strike>

EDIT: Since my first approach was wrong...
First you should start by inspecting your URL (myEndpointAddress in your code). Can you browse to it in a browser (you can set a breakpoint on that line, then copy the value and paste it into your browser).

If that works or if there is an error shown when you browse to it, then add this to your web.config of the web app hosting the WCF service inside of the

```
<system.diagnostics> <sources> <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true"> <listeners> <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData= "Trace.svclog" /> </listeners> </source> </sources> </system.diagnostics>
```

Then run your application or browse to it. It will create a Trace.svclog file in the same directory as your web application. Open up that file and look for the highlighted in red entry. That will give you more information on the exception. WCF doesn't return the full information by default to slow down malicious users.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I already tried this.
The problem is that the method is never called (as the webservice address is not valid), so the RegisterUserCompleted is never reached.